# SQL separate / single variable escape with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, pdo

I know how to escape with PDO using `prepare` statements in PHP.

However I would like to escape separate variable which then will be used >>not escaped<< by other framework (wordpress).

```
$my_var = "something";
$my_var = PSEUDO_SINGLE_PDO_ESCAPE( $my_var );
use_elswhere('do_something', $my_var);
```

Is there a way how to achieve this using PDO?

Or how should I sanitize this var?

**EDIT:** I just found out that wordpress has its own sql escape function [`esc_sql()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_sql) which returns *"Escaped value appropriate for use in a SQL query.*"        Used like `$var = esc_sql( $var );`

Comment: How exactly do you want to escape? For what? Which characters? There are different types: `\'` to escape a quote in the PHP string. `%20` to escape a space for a URL, etc.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I want to esacpe the var same as it would with `PDO::PARAM_STR` in PDO's `prepare` method.

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

Comment: Exactly what I needed :) It was actually in one of my opened tabs already but I was not sure :) , make a nice answer and you will get accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape like PDO you can use:

```
$conn   = new PDO('sqlite:/home/lynn/music.sql3');
$string = 'Nice';
echo "Unquoted string: $string\n";
echo "Quoted string: " . $conn->quote($string) . "\n";
```

See:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

So you don't have to think about what characters to escape and how.

Do note that the type of database you connect to influences the escape.

Comment: and can I ask one more question? what's with the "sqlite:/home/lynn/music.sql3" is it a way of creating some sort of "virtual" PDO connection, so PDO's methods can be used ? :)

Comment: There's nothing virtual about that connection. You need a connection to an existing, or new, database, for PDO::quote() to work. Each database type is escaped differently in PDO. As I said there are many ways of escaping strings.